# Conditionally passing a named keyword argument to a function

Tags: python

I'm not sure if I'm using the correct wording in my question but the situation I have is that I'm calling a function and passing a value to one of its named keyword arguments only if I have a value for it. A simplified example of how I'm currently doing it:

```
var_1 = data.get("var_1", None)

if var_1:
    some_function(some_arg=var_1)
else:
    some_function()
```

The function `some_function()` does not accept setting `some_arg` to None so I can only call the function with the named argument if I have a valid value for it.

The reason why the above is less desirable for me is that the actual function calls I'm making have a bunch (5+) of named arguments that I set. This results in repeating mostly similar function calls that differ by only one parameter.

Is there a better way/more Pythonic way to do this? I wish I could call the function and set all possible named parameters that I might wish to pass but, at runtime, only pass in the values that I actually have something for.

In case it matters, the function calls are to the AWS Python SDK (Boto3) so I can't alter the behavior of the function.

Comment: Does `some_arg` have a known default, or is it a strictly optional keyword argument (extracted from `**kwargs`, for example)?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

What you can do is:

```
var_1 = data.get("var_1", None)
fun_kwargs = {'some_arg': var_1} if var_1 else {}
some_function(**fun_kwargs)
```

If you have multiple parameters you could do:

```
fun_kwargs = {}
if var1: fun_kwargs['some_arg1'] = var_1
if var2: fun_kwargs['some_arg2'] = var_2
if var3: fun_kwargs['some_arg3'] = var_3
some_function(**fun_kwargs)
```

Comment: Is this method extensible to multiple arguments? e.g. both a `var_1` and `var_2` for two different kwargs?

Comment: @swigganicks Yes, just fill a `dict` with whatever is available and pass it to the function with `**`. I have added an example with a possible way to do it.